# React router doesn't apply NavLink active class if the component has mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am using `react-router` with `NavLink`, because I want to set style for the active link. This is Menu component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Menu extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <nav>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/"
                activeClassName="active" exact={true}>Home</NavLink>

            <NavLink className="nav-link to="/messages"
                activeClassName="active" exact={true}>Messages</NavLink>
```

The Menu component is included in another component `Header`, which uses `mapStateToProps`:

```
....
    return(
        <div>
            ....
            <Menu />
        </div>
....

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return  {....}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

And I have `RouterApp` where are included `Header` and PageComponents:

```
....
const store = configureStore();


const AppRouter = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/messages" component={MessagesPage} exact={true} />
                    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                </Switch>
           </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>
);
```

When I access root route in the browser, home link is with a class `active` and the component is `HomePage`.

If I click on messages link, the correct component is rendered - `MessagesPage`, but home link stays with the `activeClass` and `NavLink` for messages isn't with it.

If I remove `mapStateToProps` from `Header` component, everything works fine, but with it, the active class doesn't apply to the current link.

Comment: In the Header comp I see a `mapDispatchToProps` (not being passed in as the second arg to connect) and no `mapStateToProps` func but being passed in... Also all of the exacts are not needed but they won't really hurt... Otherwise looks ok to me...

Comment: Hi, thanks. i have edited the question. Just was copied the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the `Header` component as a default `Route` or use `withRouter` HOC ant the components Navlink would work correctly

```
<Route component={Header}/>
```

or

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Header));
```